# i am trying to use raw string concept but finding error

Tags: python, string, rawstring

program:

```
d=r'he said,'let's python.''
print(d)
```

output:

```
File "<ipython-input-39-bb6666c2121c>", line 1
d=r'he said,'let's python.''
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you want to use `'` in string wrap it with `"` for eg. `"he said,'let's python.'"` or escape single quotes for eg. `'he said,\'let\'s python.\''`

Comment: `r` prefix does not escape quotes for you. It merely let's you use escape sequences as literal characters (so, `\n` will be a literal `'\n'` rather than a new line)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the raw string in double quotes. This is one way to deal with situations where you may have single quotes(or double quotes) representing the string boundaries and also exist within the string. In our case, we denote the string boundaries with double quotes since the single quote(apostrophe) appears in the word ***let's***.

```
>>> d=r"he said,'let's python."
>>> print(d)
he said,'let's python.
```

Answer (score 1):

You got `SyntaxError` because `r'he said,'let's python.''` is not legal [python literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) - as you used single `'` at ends we are dealing with `shortstring` which must consist of elements which are `<any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>` and you tried to use quote inside so it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your message, which includes single quotes ('), with double quotes (") to make the syntax work. In your case:

```
d = r"he said,'let's python."
print(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

If your string includes ' or " you must put a backslash in front of it.